# Error in batch file "..unexpected at this time batch file"

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I have a code in a batch file which is giving an error:

```
56 was unexpected at this time
```

at `if condition (if %fileSize% == 9363)`

My code is:

```
for %%F in ("site_data.csv") 

   do set "fileSize=%%~zF" 

   if %fileSize% == 9363 
   (
      pause
      set sum2=%TIME:~3,2% 

      echo sum2=%sum2%
      pause

      if /f %sum2% gtr %sum1% 
      (
         goto :p3
      )

      goto :p2
   )
```

I don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: Your double equals comparison has unexpected tokens.  It expects a specific datatype, and you gave it something unexpected.  Double check the datatypes of each variable used in the comparison, and make sure they are compatible for double equals.  Try forcing each variable to be a string like this: `if "%fileSize% == "9363"`

Answer (score 2):

The "/F" parameter doesn't exist, please see the command help:

```
IF /?
```

And SUM1 variable doesn't exist in the example code that you given, so that can be another problem.

Try this:

```
@Echo OFF
for %%F in ("site_data.csv") do (set "fileSize=%%~zF") 

IF %fileSize% EQU 9363 (set /A sum2=%TIME:~3,2%)
if %sum2% gtr %sum1% (goto :p3) ELSE (goto :p2)
```

Comment: the close parentheses for the do loop should come after the end of your example, so that the code in the inner loop is executed after each file. Also, you may need to look at using *delayed expansion*, and `!FileSize!`

Comment: Why you say the parentheses of my example are bad? the FOR is not for procesing the contents of the file, it's only to check one time the filesize of the CSV file and that's it what the user want, or at least what the user posted in her example, all is good in my example. thanks for comment.